Does “A big gamer” mean a person who likes playing games?
Can we use the phrase 'big gamer' to refer to someone who loves playing video games? If so, what other kinds of words can we use 'big' with?

Here on ELL, we’re big fans of demonstrating you’ve tried to find an answer on your own before posting a question.

@PaulTanenbaum I asked Gemini, an AI software similar to ChatGPT, and it suggested this phrase to me. However, when I searched Google, I didn't find many examples of this phrase being used. So, I came here to ask! You don’t have to answer me but you shouldn’t be so harsh on me like that, especially when you haven’t heard the whole story”

I didn’t intend harshness, I’m sorry if it came out that way. And note that  the reason I didn’t know the whole story is that you hadn’t shared it. Note too that the comment that seemed to you harsh does provide an answer.

I’d  also add a recommendation: Do not rely on AI models’ advice on English usage, it can be wildly wrong.

@PaulTanenbaum Oh, so the default rule here is to show that you have done your research. I have to show it, not just do it. I didn't know that. If that's the rule, my apologize. I'll show my research next time.

No problem. One reason for that expectation is to prevent people’s hoping others will do their work for them (which I am not saying you were). But the stronger reason is that when we know what someone has tried, what they’ve found, and why it’s insufficient for them, it allows us to provide much better-aimed answers.

You might want to check out our help center, which lays out a lot of info about how to ask good questions, what our conventions are, etc.

It's in Merriam-Webster dictionary: "big 2a : filled with or characterized by enthusiasm and interest". Its examples are "big fan", "big baker", "big shopper".

Also, big idiot, big fool etc. Used in insults all the time too.

"Big gamer" is definitely a good phrase! You can use "big" to describe many similar things. Other examples include:

Big fan
Big nerd
Big movie-buff (movie fan)
Big show-off (someone who plays up bombastically or boasts, particularly to others)
Big cook (someone who enjoys cooking)

In some of these examples, substituting "big" for "keen" does not work, E.G. "keen nerd" & "keen show-off" don't really sound right to me at all.
Whilst "keen golfer" may be more used than "big golfer", we're not talking about golf - we're talking about gaming! We are also probably talking about a completely different group of people, older golfers and younger gamers.

In the cited context, it would be ambiguous whether big means keen (as in He's big on gaming) or well-known (as in He's big in gaming). But consider this usage chart...

I suppose it's also possible that big might be used literally (large-boned and/or overweight), but that would be relatively even more uncommon than the two primary figurative usages.
My advice for learners is to use unambiguous keen / famous or equivalent in such contexts, but it's no biggie either way.
